# Activemessaging caused infinite loop in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activemessaging

In my rails app, activemessaing caused an infinite loop, e.g. when I run bundle install, an error message is given:

"Your Gemfile requires gems that depend on each other, creating an infinite loop. Please remove gem 'activemessaging' and try again."

Any ideas?

### Gemfile

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'

gem 'rails_config'
gem 'nokogiri-pretty'
gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_ldap_authenticatable'

gem "activemessaging"
gem 'stomp'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'daemons'
```

Comment: The reason seems to be that activemessaging depends on itself.Remove this cyclic dependency and all should go well again

Comment: I need to use activemessaging in my app. It used to work on another server with same version of Ruby(2.1.5) and Rails(4.2.0).

Comment: I guess we'll need to see the `Gemfile`.

Comment: attached Gemfile above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message suggests, the problem is caused by the infinite loop dependency, e.g. activemessaging depends on itself. Check the gem spec in activemessaging to see if there is a self dependency defined.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it fixed.

Just refer activemessaging to my forked version:

gem "activemessaging", :git => "https://github.com/digital-york/activemessaging.git"

The changes I've made is just to comment out self dependencies in the gem spec.